# Angular connecting to a Laravel backend with Sanctum installed returning a null token on app, but api shows the token

Tags: angular, laravel, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic Angular mobile app and it connects to a Laravel backend which has Sanctum setup for tokens.

I am requesting the token from
`https://my_domain.com/sanctum-cookie`

When I send a get request using Postman, I get a response code 204 and I can see the XSRF-TOKEN on the headers.

When i execute my code below, I also get a response code of 204, but I am unable to access the token. When I console log the response, the headers are empty.

I am using HttpClientModule in Angular and do not want to use axios as the application is at an advanced stage using HttpClientModule.

Below is my code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment.prod";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/services/user/user.service';
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  xsrfToken: string = '';

  headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
    'XSFR-TOKEN' : this.xsrfToken,
  });

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private user: UserService
  ) { }


  loginUser(credentials: { email: string; password: string }): Promise<{ success: boolean, user?: any }> {
    console.log('Logging in the user with credentials =>', credentials.email + ' ' + credentials.password);
    // Perform validation on email and password
    if (credentials.email == '' || credentials.password == '') {
      return Promise.resolve({ success: false }); // Return false if email or password is null
    } else {
      //********LOGIN LOGIC
      return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrlForCookie}`, {headers: this.headers, observe: 'response' }).toPromise()
        .then((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
          const setCookieHeader = response.headers.get('Set-Cookie');
          if (setCookieHeader) {
            const csrfToken = setCookieHeader.split(';')[0].split('=')[1];
            console.log('CSRF Token:', csrfToken);
            this.xsrfToken = csrfToken;
          }
          console.log('CSRF Token => ' , setCookieHeader);

          // Once CSRF token is fetched, proceed with login
          return this.http.post(`${environment.api}/login`, credentials, {headers: this.headers, observe: 'response' }).toPromise()
            .then((loginResponse: HttpResponse<any>) => {
              if (loginResponse.body.status == 'error') {
                console.error('Error occurred:', loginResponse.body.message);
                return { success: false };
              } else {
                console.log('User logged in:', loginResponse.body.user);
                return { success: true, user: loginResponse.body.user }; // Return user object along with success status
              }
            });
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          console.error('Fatal error occurred:', error.message);
          return { success: false };
        });
      //**********END OF LOGIN LOGIC
    }
  }//End of login function


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Set-Cookie` headers are not accessible from javascript within a browser by design.

See also [MDN for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

> Warning: Browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing the `Set-Cookie` header, as required by the Fetch spec, which defines `Set-Cookie` as a forbidden response-header name that must be filtered out from any response exposed to frontend code.